# What does Wordpress do on just the home page (slow loading)?

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization

I have a problem with a wordpress site and I really can't figure out what causes it.

All the pages in the site load perfectly fine, they are quite stuffed with content but the load time is ok and so is memory usage as they have no problem with a 32M memory limit set in `wp-settings.php`.

The problem comes with the home page. It takes several seconds to load (excluding other content, just the main request) and fails (where 'fails' stands for blank page shown) unless I raise the memory limit **above 300M**.

#### Possible suggestion 1: check `index.php` code

Done. I replaced it with a blank page only containing the word `TEST`, still same slow loading and blank page.

#### Possible suggestion 2: disable all plugins

Done. Disabled each and every plugin and still same exact behaviour.

#### My current workaround

The only thing that I could find to temporarily solve the issue, is redirecting (via wordpress' internal rewrite) any request for `/` to a custom page which is linked to `index.php`. This way I have the homepage working fine, quickly and under the 32M memory limit.

Now, this works but it's a horribly dirty hack, so how can I find out what wordpress is doing when I ask for the home page **before** loading the template given that it has nothing to do with plugins?

Comment: Check your error log, when a blank page is produces this means the error_reporting is switched of, so errors will only be in the logs, you should get an error something like `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXX bytes ...`

Comment: Yes but that doesn't help me understand the problem. I already know it fails due to not enough available memory: the point is why?

Comment: The point is Check your Error log... it will tell you what point in the application the memory becomes exhausted, then you manually trace back to index and find out what's causing it, yes 'Manually' trace back, no pain... no game.

Answer (score 2):

If you've tried replacing index.php with just plain text then i would definitely check your .htaccess file for errors, extra characters, or some type of invalid configuration. Disable it and see if that helps for starters.

Answer (score 1):

To see if anything comes out try adding WP_DEBUG=true to wp-config.php
Might show you if something else is erroring earlier 
But otherwise yes kachegrind or xdebug definately

Also if on unix and you have access try strace command on the apache process

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to tell, but there is a way to find out: use the [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) profiler, and then use [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) or its [windows port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) to view its results. It will show you lots of data, including a visual chart, which will hopefully be very helpful in identifying where is PHP spending most of its time...

Comment: I'll see if I can install it (I'm not sure, server is not mine)

Comment: Never install that on a production server. Download your site and install everything on your local computer. It is great for development but it can be a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server itself doing any pre/post processing on the homepage?

Turning on PHP errors may shed some light on the process as will looking at the httpd error log.

Out of curiosity, are you positive your site hasn't been hijacked?

Comment: No other processince that I'm awary of, just normal wordpress page life cycle. Error reporting only shows several notices for undefined indexes. I'm positive the server is clean.